# How to get system properties (UUID/logged in user) using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, uuid

I want to get the system (windows/linux) properties such as, UUIDand logged in user information.
Since MAC address can be changed, I had preferred UUID.

I had developed a mozilla firefox browser extension, from which I need to read these two parameters and check against the license string available in a file.

Is there way to achieve this using *javascript* or any javascript libraries like *JQuery.* Is there any security violations implies here?

Comment: AFAIK you can't get MAC address with JavaScript anyway. I don't know if Firefox exposes this data to its plugins though, but I'd be quite surprised if it does.

Comment: I'd be surprised if that was possible, but I'm not in a position to say that it's definitely not.

Comment: Since it's a Firefox extension you have access to the `system` module: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/system  but I'm affraid it won't be enough for your needs.